# Deploying ReacjtJS App to Linux

Tags: reactjs

I have created a test application on my Mac. After I run `npm run build`, it created a build directory. Here starts the problem.

I have uploaded build directory to linux running an apache server. But i don't see it working. Do i need to install node, npm or upload whole directory to get it working?

The strange thing is, after i upload the build directory to the root of web server, I only see the first page. I am using react-router and first page renders the first component. example.com works fine but example.com/browse or example.com/fruit/apple does not work. Think of that you are missing htaccess file.

So are there any docs to show how can i make this work? Because when i search for deployment the only think i see is `npm run build` and `serve`

Comment: could you provide more info? like how are you serving?

Comment: I have added a .htaccess file and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem adding the following .htaccess file to my root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
```